# How to fix IBPP::LogicException: Unknown or unsupported statement type?

Tags: c++, firebird, c++20, firebird-3.0

I'm working with [C++ API for firebird](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ibpp/) database.

I can connect with the database, but when I try to execute an statement, I get this error:

```
*** IBPP::LogicException ***
Context: Statement::Prepare
Message: Unknown or unsupported statement type
```

The piece of code of my class on get this error is this (following the **Executing statements section** on the [reference documentation samples](http://www.ibpp.org/reference/samples)):

```
try
{
    this->database = IBPP::DatabaseFactory(
        ServerName,
        DatabaseName,
        UserName,
        UserPassword);
    this->database->Connect();
}
catch(IBPP::Exception& e)
{
    cout << e.ErrorMessage() << endl;
}

IBPP::Transaction tr = IBPP::TransactionFactory(this->database);
IBPP::Statement st = IBPP::StatementFactory(this->database, tr);

if (this->database->Connected() == false) {
    throw "No database!!!";
}

try
{
    tr->Start();

    st->Prepare("SELECT a.ID from test a");

    st->Execute();
    tr->Commit();

}
catch (IBPP::Exception &e)
{
    tr->Rollback();
    cerr << e.ErrorMessage() << endl;
}
```

I can't understand this error, because this code is the same as the reference!
I cant find anything about this anywhere.

**My fault. The IBPP API only cover 2.5.x Firebird version. I tested on 3.0.x**

Comment: I don't know IBPP, but I don't see why this wouldn't work on Firebird 3, but would work with Firebird 2.5. The (legacy) client API is the same, and AFAIK, nothing has changed with regard to statement types for select statements between these two versions

Comment: does this exactly statement work in FlameRobin ? If it does, can you just take FlameRobin sources and learn from them ?